# Extract parts of string with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following tag in xml:

```
<GameESRB> Mature10+ </GameESRB>
```

I want to get all the characters that are not lowercase using XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0. Thus the result string for the above would be:

```
 M10+
```

How would I go about into doing this?

Comment: No chance to switch to XPath/XSLT 2.0? It does have ````fn:replace```` and this would make it much simpler: ````replace($node, "[a-z]", "")````

Comment: No sorry. It is a University project and IT is stated that we are only allowed to use version 1.0.

Comment: @dirkk: I wouldn't say that `replace` was *"much simpler"* than the equivalent `translate` in this instance. It is the difference between `"[a-z]"` and `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`.

Comment: @Borodin I agree, I didn't know about the ````translate```` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use** (with `GameESRB` as the initial context node):

```
translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:copy-of select="translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<GameESRB> Mature10+ </GameESRB>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated, and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
 M10+
```